# In Jeremiah 23:6, is the phrase “the LORD our Righteousness” a title or just the meaning of the name?

Tags: jeremiah, messiah

Jeremiah 23:5-6 (CJB):

> 5 “The days are coming,” says Adonai when I will raise a righteous
>   Branch for David. He will reign as king and succeed, he will do what
>   is just and right in the land.6 In his days Y’hudah will be
>   saved,Isra’el will live in safety, and the name given to him will be
>   Adonai Tzidkenu [Adonai our righteousness].

The verse states that the name given this person shall be “Adonai our Righteousness”. This word structure appears to be a title and not just the meaning of the name. Is this view correct?

Comment: Will you elaborate how 'this word structure appears to be a title'? I only see it as a name. I think I am missing something.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking about the KJV when I wrote that: "and this is his name whereby he shall be called". Sounds like a title and not another name that "means" the LORD our Righteousness. Rather, His name IS...

Comment: The Hebrew states 'The LORD - righteousness'. The 'our' is not there in the original.My understanding is that this is the stating of an equivalence.Two things are stated without  any other grammar. They are equivalent.

Comment: 'Our' is there in the original. The ending of the word for 'righteousness' modifies it to 'righteousness of us'.

Comment: "LORD" is a substitute made some 7,000 times for God's proper "name" which is "Yahweh" for the Hebrew and "Jehovah" in English.

The following says:-
"YHVH" is the Hebrew word that translates as "LORD". Found more often in the Old Testament than any other name for God (approximately 7,000 times), the title is also referred to as the "Tetragrammaton," meaning the "The Four Letters". YHVH comes from the Hebrew verb "to be" and is the special name that God revealed to Moses at the burning bush."-https://www.allaboutgod.com/names-of-god.htm

Comment: @ Jack; So can you comment on the nature of the name, ie is this just another example of a name that has the meaning of the LORD our Righteousness, ie similar to a name that ends in "el" (eg Joel, YHWH is God)? OR, is this his name?

Comment: For some reason the Complete Jewish Bible renders YHVH as Adonai which is completely incorrect and misleading. Please cite a different Bible. Thanks. In the meantime -1.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got it now.

Jeremiah 23:5, 6 **Added [ ]**

“Look! The days are coming [prophecy],” declares Jehovah, “when I will raise up to David a righteous sprout [Jesus; see Isa. 11:1; “stump” of Jesse, King David’s father*].  And a king [Jesus] will reign and show insight and uphold justice and righteousness in the land. 6 In his days Judah will be saved, and Israel [faithful Christianized Jews and Gentiles] will reside in security.  And this is the name by which he [Jesus] will be called: Jehovah Is Our [his collective of followers] Righteousness.**”

The “our” (plural) is the collective body of Christianized Jews and Gentiles, God’s people, serving in unity under the King from the Royal line of David via Jesse, King David’s father (Isa 11:1).

Support texts:-

Jeremiah 33:14, 15 NWT

“‘Look! The days are coming,’ declares Jehovah, ‘when I will fulfill the good promise that I have spoken concerning the house of Israel and the house of Judah. 15 In those days and at that time I will cause to sprout for David **a righteous sprout [Jesus],** and he will execute justice and righteousness in the land.

*Isa 11:1 NJB

“A **shoot** will spring from the stock of Jesse, a new shoot will grow from his roots.”

**Psalm 40:8, 9 NWT

"To do your will, O my God, is my [Jesus'] delight, And your law is deep within me [Jesus'].  9 I proclaim the good news of righteousness in the great congregation.. . .